# Setting Initial Conditions in a System of Differential Equations that don't start at t=0

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of six differential equations (linear for the sake of the discussion). I want to set the initial condition to start at time t=18 and not time t=0. I know the values of the dependent variables at t=18 because they derive from the experimental data. So let's say I have an ode describing x(t) and y(t) and I want to start the differential equation at t=18 as my initial condition. How do I do this? I have looked at a myriad of examples at they all start off with x(0)=some value and y(0)=some value. What I need is for Mathematica to solve the system starting from the initial conditions of x(18) and y(18). Ideas?

Comment: Just use the condition x[18]==some value...

Comment: They always start at t=0 since you can always change to another variable t' = t -18 and the equations remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for the info. That seems really weird that you cannot do something like

Comment: Sorry, hit the return key. To finish, seems strange that you cannot do something like

Comment: set tstart=18 and then do something like u[tstart]=value

Comment: It seems you ignored the very first comment which has the answer, and only looked at the second comment.

Answer (score 1):

The second comment on this post is incorrect.  You can set a condition for any time `t0`, whether initial or not.  Independently of this, you can solve the equation for any interval of the variable. Example:

```
NDSolve[{f'[t] == -f[t], f[2] == 1}, f, {t, 1, 3}]
```

Here the equation is solved for the interval $t \in [1,3]$, but the condition is set for $t == 2$ as `f[2] == 1`.

You can even have the condition outside of the solution range:

```
NDSolve[{f'[t] == -f[t], f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 1, 3}]
```